# How to enable the next textfield in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I have two textfields (a username and a password) field and I remember that sometimes the keyboard has a little < or > to navigate through the textfields and I was wondering if there is an option or code that would allow me to do this natively in my app. Any tips or hints are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: check this link http://code4app.net/category/textfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like an acceptable solution that doesn't involve implementing a third party library, you can do it like the following:

Set the return button on the virtual keyboard to be a "Next" button for the username field, and a "Go" button for the password field, and make your view controller a `UITextFieldDelegate`. Set your view controller as the delegate for both text fields, then implement the `textFieldShouldReturn:` like the following:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    if (textField == self.username) {
        [self.password becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    else if (textField == self.password) {
        [self.password resignFirstResponder];
        [self signInPressed];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

This will make it so if you have the username field selected, the "Next" button on the keyboard will advance to the password field, and when the password field is selected, the "Go" button will call the `signInPressed` method, which you just change to whatever you have your sign in method named.

Answer (score 0):

There's no builtin way to add these buttons.

Look into [`inputAccessoryView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html) to understand how to extend the keyboard.